# Cannot convert value of type to expected argument type (Swift 1.2 -> swift 2)

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7

I'm trying to use Apple's keychain service based on a tutorial I found (https://www.raywenderlich.com/85528/user-accounts-ios-ruby-rails-swift#next_section). However I am shown this error

> Cannot convert value of type 'Unmanaged< AnyObject>'?' to expected argument type 'AnyObject?'

At this block of codes

```
var dataTypeRef : Unmanaged<AnyObject>?
let status = SecItemCopyMatching(queryAttributes, &dataTypeRef)

if dataTypeRef == nil {
  return nil
}
```

The full code block is as shown below

```
public class func passwordForAccount(account: String, service: String = "keyChainDefaultService") -> String? {
let queryAttributes = NSDictionary(objects: [secClassGenericPassword(), service, account, true], forKeys: [secClass(), secAttrService(), secAttrAccount(), secReturnData()])

var dataTypeRef : Unmanaged<AnyObject>?
let status = SecItemCopyMatching(queryAttributes, &dataTypeRef)

if dataTypeRef == nil {
  return nil
}

let retrievedData : NSData = dataTypeRef!.takeRetainedValue() as! NSData
let password = NSString(data: retrievedData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

return (password as! String)
}
```

The entire code can be found here (https://codeshare.io/426px) at line 52- 57.

Comment: if you are not used the `status` in anywhere in your class, no need to declare or create, hide that bro

Comment: Oops I typed the wrong error message out.. haha my bad

Comment: Why is tagged as Rails? Here is nothing about Rails.

Comment: My bad corrected that mistake

Comment: @noobdev - your problem is solved bro

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik What do you mean?

Comment: i'm seeing you posted four different  posts with same type of problem. instead of post your question first try to figure out what's the issue.